# Integrate web text into App (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am having a news section in the App and i want to renew it through a website that shows the text and pictures it should copy how do i do that?

I just want that it exactly copies the text and pictures from a website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what have you done so far. some code and research or anything.

Comment: You can do this by RSS feed of news.

Comment: Its own News for a Garage not real News

Comment: From some website you want to display news as text and pictures, right ?

Comment: Yes exactly thats what i want.

Comment: So just simply open that URL in UIWebView. or Copy though each text and image on your server and make API to display on app or make RSS feed like https://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/rss-reader-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UIWebView for that! First, drop a web view on the scene and then:
Here is the code for **SWIFT 2**:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad(){
super.viewDidLoad()

let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")   // instead of "http://www.google.com", you put the website link you want, but with "http://" or "https://" 

let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
}
```

}

Version For **SWIFT 3**:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "http://www.booking.com")   // instead of "http://www.google.com", you put the website link you want, but with "http://" or "https://"

        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)

        webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    }

}
```

Comment: Now that I read your answer once again, I realised that it might not be quite what you wanted, but I don't think that there is another way of doing it. I don't think that swift can extract the photos and text only

Comment: still, if it helped you a bit, at least, let me know

Comment: Hey thanks i have a question i get unresolved identifier

Comment: Can you be more explicit? Where

Comment: Tell me the line and I think I Can help you. And also provide your code, please

Answer (score 0):

So at the end you need to implement rss reader if your website supports.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/rss-reader-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app

If website does not support then you could implement below ways.

Open that URL in UIWebView or Copy though each text and image on your server and make API to display on app.